# Render an object from array onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to render a single question onClick from each array. If i click the truth array should render a question from that one and if i click the dare array do the same. My project is to create a truth or dare game using reactjs as i want to learn from this.

My code is as follow:

**Questions.js**

```
const truth = [
  {question: "Question 1", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 2", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 3", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 4", hasAppeard: false}
]

const dare = [
  {question: "Question 5", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 6", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 7", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 8", hasAppeard: false}
]
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    truthQuest: null,
    dareQuest: null
  }
}

handleRandomTruth = () => {
  this.setState({
  truthQuest: Math.round(Math.random() * 9 + 1)
  })
}

handleRandomDare = () => {
  this.setState({
  dareQuest: Math.round(Math.random() * 9 + 1)
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="timer">
        <CountdownTimer />
      </div>

      <div className="current-player">
        <h3>current player</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="next-player">
        <h3>next player</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="questions">
         {truth[Object.keys(this.state.truthQuest
         {dare[this.state.dareQuest]}
      </div>

      <button className="btn-truth" onClick= 
       {this.handleRandomTruth}>Truth</button>
      <button className="btn-dare" onClick= 
       {this.handleRandomDare}>Dare</button>
      <button className="btn-home" >Home</button>
  </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using your `truthQuest` and `dareQuest` variables in any way?

Comment: What is the purpose of `{truth[Object.keys(this.state.truthQuest`? It's a syntactic error. Also, you will be displaying 2 questions at a time.  You need to put your truth/dare question rendering inside an `if` statement to check which type of question you want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to only show 1 question at a time, in your component HTML, you can just set a `currQuestion` variable on your state, rather than a separate truth/dare question, as that is unnecessary. I made a few other minor changes as well, as they make things simpler.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    currQuest: null
  }
}

handleRandomTruth = () => {
  this.setState({
    currQuest: truth[Math.floor(Math.random() * truth.length)]
  })
}

handleRandomDare = () => {
  this.setState({
    currQuest: dare[Math.floor(Math.random() * dare.length)]
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className="current-player">
        <h3>current player</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="next-player">
        <h3>next player</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="questions">
         {this.state.currQuest ? <div>{this.state.currQuest.question}</div> : ''}
      </div>

      <button className="btn-truth" onClick= 
       {this.handleRandomTruth}>Truth</button>
      <button className="btn-dare" onClick= 
       {this.handleRandomDare}>Dare</button>
      <button className="btn-home" >Home</button>
  </div>
  )};
}
```